# data tables created through ajax data get empty when search for a keyword or change per page entries

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I am working with Jquery data tables and append rows through ajax call success function. It works fine but when I try to filter data through input type search, the table get empty. Also when I try to change per page entries drop down, table get empty.
Below are the table screen shots.

**Table photo with data**
[image]

---

---

**Table photo with error**
[image]

---

---

This is my ajax code

```html
$.ajax
  ({
   type:'POST',
   url:'MyFunction',
   data:{'Id':Id},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
    var dataString=JSON.stringify(data);
    var dataArray=Array();
    dataArray=dataString.split('},');
    for(var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++)
    {
     var Array0=dataArray[i].split(',');
     var date0=Array0[2];
     var date1=date0.replace('"Purchase_date":"','');
     var date2=date1.replace('"','');
     
     var product0=Array0[15];
     var product1=product0.replace('"Product_name":"','');
     var product2=product1.replace('"','');
     
     
     var amount0=Array0[3];
     var amount1=amount0.replace('"Purchase_amount":"','');
     var amount2=amount1.replace('"','');
     
     var payed0=Array0[5];
     var payed1=payed0.replace('"Purchase_payed":"','');
     var payed2=payed1.replace('"','');
     
     var balance0=Array0[6];
     var balance1=balance0.replace('"Purchase_balance":"','');
     var balance2=balance1.replace('"','');
     
     var htm='';
     htm+=' <tr class="odd gradeX">';
     htm+='  <td>';
     htm+=   date2;
     htm+='  </td>';
     htm+='  <td>';
     htm+=   product2;
     htm+='  </td>';
     htm+='  <td>';
     htm+=   amount2;
     htm+='  </td>';
     htm+='  <td>';
     htm+=   payed2;
     htm+='  </td>';
     htm+='  <td>';
     htm+=   balance2;
     htm+='  </td>';
     htm+=' </tr>';
     
     $("#MyTable tbody").append(htm);
    }
   }
  });
```

Where I am wrong.

Comment: You are appending data to the table and not using dt's internal functions to add the data properly to the table thus not all of the features are properly functioning. Please read: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: @gulzar ali, you are appending data to datatable, instead of loading using ajax. so if you see your pagination it displaying "showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi better way to add new row in datatable add through datatable object not direct through table element when you are appending new row to table without datatable object you are breaking datatable check this example

```
var t = $('#example').DataTable();
t.row.add([date2,product2,amount2,payed2,balance2]);
```

https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html